# What solution quality can we expect for a linear programming solver?

Tags: linear-programming, glpk

I am trying to solve linear constraint satisfaction problems.  So I grabbed the "GNU Linear Programming Kit," wrote my constraints, and let it loose on it with some simple objective function.

GLPK claimed to find a solution, but if I check it against the constraints, they are not satisfied.  Namely an expression that should be <= 0 is actually around 1e-10.  I.e., slightly greater than 0.

I can probably live with the issue, by setting up my constraints to return the Chebyshev centre of the polyhedron, but I wonder if such discrepancies are to be expected with linear programming solvers, or I should report it as a bug for the GLPK folks.

Answer (score 0):

All LP solvers use feasibility and other tolerances. These are needed because floating-point computations are not exact. You can tighten them a bit, but in general, it is better not to touch them.

So, you should expect solutions with the following properties:

- variables are slightly outside their bounds
- constraints may be violated by a small amount
- binary and integer variables are slightly non-integer